# String Unknown pattern Matching

Tags: string, pattern-recognition

I want to determine an unknown pattern in a string such as,

s=112468112468112468112468112468.

So in this string, we can clearly see that 112468 is the repeating pattern. I searched
on google quite a bit for finding some algorithms to help me, but I could only see ones which find  a given pattern in a string such as Boyer-Moore algorithm etc.

What I do now to find these repeating unknown pattern is that,

```
for(i=0;i<Length of String;i++)
{
  for(j=i+1;j<Length of String;j++)
  {
    if(s[i]==s[j] && s[i+1]==s[j+1] && s[i+2]==s[j+2] && s[i+3]==s[j+3])
    {
       patternlength=j-i;

           for(k=i;k<j;k++)
           {
            pattern[k]=s[i+k]
           }
     }
   }
}
```

Although this works for the given string by using a comparison window of 4 literals, it may very well not work for some other string. Does anybody know a better solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Having a machine identify any patterns in text is not a trivial problem. Are you **only** interested in, for example, strings with repeating patterns? If you can give us the **type** or pattern or patterns for which you are interested in searching, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Well the kind of patterns I am dealing with will be strings with repeating patterns and would be very similar to the one I have written above as "s" and. The method which I have coded above works for me juss fine. But I just wanted to know if there is some standard algorithm for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not pattern matching, this is pattern *recognition*, which is fundamentally different and potentially much harder.

However, the simple kind of pattern exhibited by this string could have been found using (Python code):

```
def find_repeated_pattern(s):
    for i in xrange(1, len(s) / 2):
        if s == s[:i] * (len(s) / i):
            return s[:i]
```

This is a naive implementation because of all its string copying, but it can be made to work in O(*n*²) time and constant space.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Actually the string in which I am supposed to find the pattern is also dynamically generated. I am not so much of a python expert but will this code snippet work for any kinda string ot is it specific to just like the code I have written.